# Joining two java streams

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

I have two java lists like this:

```
"type 1" list:
[(id:1, type: 1, value: 100), (id:2, type: 1, value: 50), ...]
"type 2" list:
[(id:1, type: 2, value: 150), (id:2, type: 2, value: 70), ...]
```

And I want something like that:

```
Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream())
.parallel()
// I need to combine somehow items with the same id for following process
// ideally to have Tuple2(l1item, l2item) after that
.groupBy(x -> x.getId())
.map ((l1item, l2item) -> {
   // some processing
}).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

AFAIK it can be implemented via:

```
Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream())
.collect(groupingBy(x -> x.getItem)).values().stream()
.map (listOftwo -> ....)
```

But I don't want that intermediate map. Any ideas ? I can use any library.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common) provides the APIs to do exactly what you want:

```
Stream.concat(a, b).parallel().groupBy(x -> x.getId()).map(..);
```

Declaration： I'm the developer of AbacusUtil.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly... there's a overloaded groupingBy that reduces the already grouped elements, something like this:

```
  Map<Boolean, Double> result = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "ag").stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(elem -> elem.startsWith("a"), 
                    Collectors.averagingInt(String::length)));

    System.out.println(result); // {false=1.0, true=1.5}
```

This groups the elements and then applies another Collector on the values, reducing them.

Comment: you understood right, it can be considered as a solution. I just wanna know are there some other options (not necessarily from standard api) that allows work with Tuple2(firstListItem, secondListItem) on reducer side.

Comment: @Normal I think that what you are trying to say is that on the reduce side you want to consume/reduce those lists in *different* ways, right? If so, then, no, not really aware if that is possible. What you could do is first groupBy and then do whatever you want with the result.

Comment: you are right, current approach leads me to write reducer code like that:

list -> {
     if (list.get(0).type == 1)   {
          ....
    } else ....
} And I'm trying to avoid that